# Spring Scheduler didnot run during DST

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, dst, quartz

In our Java application we have Spring scheduler and the configuration is as given below :

```xml
<task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="myHealthCheck" method="getStatus" cron="0 0/5 * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

During DST end on November 3rd, the scheduler (which runs every 5 minutes) didnt run for one hour. Can some one help in handling this during DST start and end.

Thanks
Shaan

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to the time zone configuration.
What is the default time zone of your host? Try running `System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault())` to check.

If the default time zone doesn't support DST (e.g. UTC), you can set the right time zone for the whole JVM by passing the system property:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Kiev
```

Alternatively, you can specify time zone for the scheduled task directly.

Unfortunately, Spring Task XSD doesn't have a property to define a time zone (http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd).

But you can use annotations. As of Spring 4, the `@Scheduled` annotation has a new `zone` attribute (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled):

> You can also use the `zone` attribute to specify the time zone in which the cron expression is resolved.

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI", zone="Europe/Kiev")
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute on weekdays only
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please provide your comment on below queries.

1) Ideally annotation supported options should be available in XML too right? ie; 
<task:scheduled ref="myHealthCheck" method="getStatus" cron="0 0/5 * * * *" zone="Europe/Kiev"/>

2) For zone, what are the allowed values? Our host server timezone is MST, so what value can i give?

Comment: XSD doesn't have `zone` attribute. See the link in my answer. Time zone should be "US/Mountain".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had one followup query on this. The issue we faced was during DST end in November. If we don't set timezone, will there be impact during DST start in March and if so, what will be the impact? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi  @Evgeniy Khyst - Can you please help?

Comment: Hi @EugeneKhyst could you help me with this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361775/scheduler-spring-boot-doesnt-work-on-the-hour-of-the-daylight-saving-time-dst) I think that is the same problem!

When I run System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault()) I got that daylight is true. I also tried "zone" but it doesn't work