# @Scheduler Spring Boot doesn't work on the hour of the daylight saving time (DST) change

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, dst

I have problem with spring boot application at V2.2 with scheduled method.

```java
@Service
public class X {
    @Scheduled(cron = "59 59 2 25-31 10 ?")
    public void changeTimeToStandardTime() {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now()+ " CHANGE TO STANDARD TIME");
        if (LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
            //do sth
        }
    }


    @Scheduled(cron = "*/20 * * * * *")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now()+" RUN TEST EVERY 20 sec");

    }
}
```

When I start my application at 2:55 AM on the last Sunday in October, when there is a time change from 3:00AM to 2:00AM, then neither the `changeTimeToStandardTime()` method nor the `test()` method will write me anything in the console, so it won't get called.
On the other hand, when I run the application at 1:00AM or 3:00AM (already after the time change), then `test()` prints the text correctly every 20 sec.

I also tried running the application at 1:00AM and changing the system time later to 2:58AM, but after jumping to 2:58AM, the `test()` method gets called once and stops writing out (hovwever it should every 20 sec)

What could be the problem?

I have `@Enablescheduling` added to the main application class.